# Double diode loop explanation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Pins + and - are the output pins of a transformer of the low side of a SMPS. Two diodes lead to a common output which leads to the final output voltage to the right. At the same time the same output creates some sort of loop.

What could possibly the purpose of such circuit? Where can I read more about this?

At first I thought that it's there to discharge the capacitors but that's not the case.

[image]

Comment: Please reverse engineer the schematic and post it here, there is a tool avalible for drawing circuits if you edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you see are two diodes in parallel with a snubber network across them: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPu74M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> *What could possibly the purpose of such circuit? Where can I read more
> about this?*

It's a half wave rectifier with a snubber. The snubber is likely present to reduce EMI emissions.